# toString() in JavaScript: why does toString() still get called since a valueOf() prototype for type conversion of object to number

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, prototype, tostring

```
let obj = {
    toString() {
        return "2";
    }
};

let n = +obj; 

alert(n);
```

Since +obj requires a number, shouldn't it use the valueOf() prototype for type conversion which returns the object. Instead it uses the toString() method and alerts 2. Please why is this so?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I'm expecting it to throw an error or NaN

Comment: "*since a valueOf() prototype for numbers exists*" - not sure how `Number.prototype.valueOf` is related?

Comment: Don't objects have Object.prototype.valueOf() that is used for type conversion of objects to numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since `+obj` requires a number, shouldn't it use the `valueOf()` prototype for type conversion which returns the object.

It actually *does* call the `valueOf` method. But since - as you say - it returns an object, not a primitive value, it is found useless. Then, the alternative is called: `toString()`, which *does* return a primitive value that is subsequently cast to a number.

You can try

```js
const obj1 = {
    valueOf() { console.log("valueOf 1"); return this; },
    toString() { console.log("toString 1"); return "1"; },
};
console.log(+obj1);

const obj2 = {
    valueOf() { console.log("valueOf 2"); return 2; },
    toString() { console.log("toString 2"); return "2"; },
};
console.log(+obj2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your should to change de toString() function by parseInt() function to get NaN response.

```js
let obj = {
    parseInt() {
        return "2";
    }
};

let n = +obj; 

alert(n);
```

Comment: Okay. But I want to understand why it is that way

Comment: Israel, the reason is because you are trying to sum a number with a string.

Comment: I am trying to convert the object to a number with unary plus